# Horizontal scrolling register form on a parallax scrolling background

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, parallax

I'm working on a members only site where I have a parallax scrolling going on, 5 background pictures long (vertical). On the top div, picture number 1, I would like to have a nice looking form scrolling horizontal. I have found two-three examples of small boxes, but my goal is to have a centered full screen form, non of the examples i found are full width. For each step of the form I need to store the information and on the last step of the form upload the information from all other steps.
An example of my thoughts can be found below. My questions are "can vertical och horizontal scrolling work together?" and can the information from the form be saved during a click to the next slide? And also this should be done in a responsive design, that is another part that I can't find any examples for. All tips and inputs are very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I think that you could just add a rhinoslider to the first div. Checkout rhinoslider.com/

Comment: thank you, haven't seen that page. This is almost what I wan't can I use this along with a Parallax scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that sounds like [your goal](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-multi-step-form-rhinoslider/). In this example you don't have to worry about saving data through different pages. Read up on the manual on Rhinosliders webpage to see how you could tweek it. Just change

> **form-step** to **width:100%**

and adjust the form to center it ;)

The responsive part is working, but as far as I can tell, you would have to reload the page after changing the screen size.

Comment: Thank you, I did use the Rhinoslider, and made my own modifications :)

Answer (score 1):

We did a horizontal Parallax Scrolling site
You can see it here. [Posicionamiento Web - SEO Parallax Horizontal Scrolling Website](http://www.posicionamientowebenbuscadores.com)

The site is

1. SEO optimized
2. Parallax Scrolling Horizontal
3. Responsive Web Design
4. HTML5
5. CSS3
6. Jquery
7. Wordpress